# Footnote line separation

Tags: spacing, footnotes, geometry

I have an article which have several footnotes. I would like to increase the space between the end of the article's text and the footnote rule.

How can I do this?

I've already tried to change the `\footskip` but it doesn't work (actually it did nothing).

I have used `\footnotesep` and it worked but I moved only the text, not the rule

Comment: Since you've tried what would be the common suggestion, it's best to show us what your current setup is. Perhaps you did it incorrectly. To do so, show us a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764).

Comment: I suppose it's something like `\footins` box, but this is only guessing at the moment

Comment: I have used \footnotesep and I could change the text position under the rule, but If I change the \footskip nothing happens

Comment: Indeed, `\footnotesep` changes the spacing between two consecutive footnotes, as well as the spacing between the rule and the first footnote.  See p. 173 of Lamport’s book (2nd ed.) for its precise definition.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add: neither `\footskip` is involved, since it is the skip between the text body (*including* footnotes) and the footer line. Off the top my head, I’d say that you need to modify `\skip\footins`.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the length you need to modify is `\skip\footins`:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\skip\footins}{24pt plus 3pt minus 3pt} % for example



\begin{document}

Some text with a footnote.\footnote{Here it is.}

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

I’m adding a picture that shows the first page ot the output you get:

[image: First page produced by the above code]

See *The TeXbook*, pp. 122-123, and the section of `ltfloat.dtx` titled “Footnotes” for a thorough explanation.

## Addition

If you are using the `geometry` package, a more polite way of doing the above is to use the `footnotesep` option:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\geometry{footnotesep = 24pt plus 3pt minus 3pt} % for example



\begin{document}

Some text with a footnote.\footnote{Here it is.}

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

Note that the name of this option is probably the source of the mistake the OP made.